# How do you delay a rendering job? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, delayed-job

This method works OK, but if I add delayed_job's handle_asychronously, I get `can't convert nil into String`:

```
  def onixtwo 
        s = render_to_string(:template=>"isbns/onix.xml.builder") 
        send_data(s, :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "onix2.1.xml")
  end
     handle_asynchronously :onixtwo
```

So rendering with delayed job is clearly having a problem with params being passed. I've tried putting this job in a rake task but `render_to_string` is a controller action - and I'm using a `current_user` variable which needs to be referenced in the controller or view only. So... what's the best way to delay a rendering job?

/////////update////////

Given that I'm currently pair-programming with a toddler, I don't have the free hands to investigate additional class methods as wisely recommended in the comments - so as a quick and dirty I tried this:

```
  def onixtwo 

   system "  s = render_to_string(:template=>'isbns/onix.xml.builder') ; send_data(s, :type=>'text/xml',:filename => 'onix2.1.xml') & "
   redirect_to isbns_path, :target => "_blank", :flash => { :success => "ONIX message being generated in the background." }

end
```

Why doesn't it work? No error message just no file produced - which is the case when I remove system ... &

Comment: I'd personally refactor out the rendering logic into a new class and invoke that from your controller (passing in the user, rather than having it looked up) and then you'll be in a better position to background process it.

Comment: Ooh, ta for that. Put the new class in lib, then? I'll have a go.

Comment: If you put it in lib (which is perfectly valid and perhaps even more 'correct') then you'll have to add lib to the autoload paths, and you may have to restart the Rack process whenever you edit the code.  If you create a subdirectory in `app` (say, 'classes'), then that code will already be on the autoload path and will be reloaded on each request in development :)

Comment: Top advice - I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is what I did, bypassing `render_to_stream` entirely. This is in /lib or app/classes (adding     `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/classes` into config/application.rb):

#classes/bookreport.rb

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'delayed_job'
require 'delayed/tasks'

class Bookreport

  # This method takes args from the book report controller. First it sets the current period. Then it sorts out which report wants calling. Then it sends on the arguments to the correct class. 
  def initialize(method_name, client, user, books)
    current_period  = Period.where(["currentperiod = ? and client_id = ?", true, client]).first
    get_class       = method_name.capitalize.constantize.new
    get_class.send(method_name.to_sym, client, user, books.to_a, current_period.enddate)
  end
end
```

#app/classes/onixtwo.rb

```
require 'builder'

class Onixtwo

  def onixtwo(client_id, user_id, books, enddate)

  report_name       = "#{Client.find_by_id(client_id).client_name}-#{Time.now}-onix-21"
  filename          = "#{Rails.root}/public/#{report_name}.xml"
  current_company   = Company.where(:client_id => client_id).first

  File.open(filename, "w") do |file|

    xml = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => file, :indent => 2)
    xml.instruct!(:xml, :version => "1.0", :encoding => "utf-8")
    xml.declare! :DOCTYPE, :ONIXMessage, :SYSTEM, "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/03/reference/onix-international.dtd"
    xml.ONIXMessage do
      xml.Header do
       #masses of Builder code goes here...
    end
  end #of file
  xmlfile = File.open(filename, "r")
  onx     = Onixarchive.new(:client_id => client_id, :user_id => user_id)
  onx.xml = xmlfile
  onx.save!

end #of method
handle_asynchronously :onixtwo

end #of class
```

Called from the view like this:

```
    = link_to("Export to ONIX 2.1", params.merge({:controller=>"bookreports"  , :action=>:new, :method_name => "onixtwo"}))
```

Via a controller like this:

```
class Books::BookreportsController < ApplicationController
#uses Ransack for search, hence the @q variable
  def new 
    @q              = Book.search(params[:q])
    @books          = @q.result.order('pub_date DESC')      
    method_name     = params[:method_name]
    Bookreport.new(method_name, @client, @user, @books)
    redirect_to books_path, :flash => {:success => t("#{method_name.to_sym}").html_safe}
  end

end
```